# Source of incompatible matrices in Matlab Voicebox code

Tags: matlab, matrix, mfcc

I am using the `melcepst` function in the Matlab Voicebox routine to obtain MFCCs from a sound file. Below is the code I'm using, with an example wav file. My actual files are 1sec wav files sampled at 48000Hz and 24 bit-depth.  The source code for `melcepst` can be found here http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/voicebox/doc/voicebox/melcepst.html, which I will reference.

Load wav file:

```
load handel.mat 
filename = 'handel.wav'
[y,Fs] = audioread('handel.wav');
audiowrite(filename, y, Fs)
```

Run `melcepst` function. File has a sample rate of 8192Hz. I specify a Hamming window ('M'), 12 cepstral coefficients, 30 triangular filters, 245 frame length, frame increment of 81 samples, and default lowest and highest filters.

```
[c,tc] = melcepst('handel.wav', 8192, 'M', 12, 30, 245, 81, 0, 0.5)
```

This returns the following error:

```
Error using max
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in melcepst (line 111)
y=log(max(m*abs(f(a:b,:)),ath));
```

Deeper digging into the `melcepst` source code reveals the source of the problem (at line 111):
Beginning at line 101:

```
[z,tc]=enframe('handel.wav',0.54-0.46*cos(2*pi*(0:245-1)'/(245-1)),81)
f=rfft(z.');
[m,a,b]=melbankm(30,245,8192,0,0.5,'t');
pw=f(a:b,:).*conj(f(a:b,:));
pth=max(pw(:))*1E-20;
ath=sqrt(pth);
y=log(max(m*abs(f(a:b,:)),ath));
```

The matrices used in the last line, `ath` and `m*abs(f(a:b,:))` are not compatible. `ath` is a 0 x 1 empty double vector column while `m*abs(f(a:b,:))` is a 30 x 0 empty double vector column.

I understand what the problem is, but it is not clear to me why this problem arises in the first place, unless there is a bug in the original source code (which seems unlikely). Is there a problem earlier in the code that gives incompatible matrices later on? I've tried this with my own files, and their own variables which are slightly different than those I specify for this example, and I still return the same error. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I presume you've changed variable names for their values in the excerpt of the code. If `ath` is empty, then so is `pw`, which means that either `f` is empty, or `a>b`. Could this be caused by your selection of input arguments?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for the suggestion. `f` is indeed empty, as is `z`, which it calls. My input arguments should be correct, and I also get the same error when I use all the default arguments. 

I've continued working on this, and think my problem was simply that I was using the full audio signal (the original wav file) as my input speech signal, instead of just the vector of samples. Thus, in the example above, if I input `y` instead of `handel.wav` into the `melcespt` function, the code runs just fine. Problem solved!

`[c,tc] = melcepst(y, 8192, 'M', 12, 30, 245, 81, 0, 0.5)`

Comment: Amanda, consider either closing the question or posting your solution as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've continued working on this, and think my problem was simply that I was using the full audio signal (the original wav file) as my input speech signal, instead of just the vector of samples. Thus, in the example above, if I input `y` instead of `handel.wav` into the `melcespt` function, the code runs just fine: 
`[c,tc] = melcepst(y, 8192, 'M', 12, 30, 245, 81, 0, 0.5);`

Problem solved.